# Executing activity without showing the layout on screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I've searched not only stackoverflow, but another sites too, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem. I'm starting now to learn Android, and I have a doubt about activities.

I have a MainActivity which creates a notification with two buttons. One is useless by now and the other (the Send button) will open an Alert with an EditText and a button to send the text to another app.

This is the code:

```
Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class);
            Intent shareActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShareActivity.class);
            PendingIntent mainActivityPIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, mainActivityIntent, 0);
            PendingIntent shareActivityPIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, shareActivityIntent, 0);

            Notification n = new Notification.InboxStyle 
                    (new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.text_notification))
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.text_notification))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(mainActivityPIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.logo, "Botão", mainActivityPIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Share", shareActivityPIntent)
                            )
                    .build();

            n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.notify(0, n);
```

As you can see, the Send button will open another Activity, which has the code below:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Mensagem");
    alert.setMessage("Digite a mensagem");


    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Enviar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      String value = input.getText().toString();
      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, value);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Enviar"));
        finishActivity(0);
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        return;
      }
    });

    alert.show();
```

This activity is responsible for opening the alert where the user will input the text and send to another application.

The situation is that when I call the activity it not only shows the alert but also open a new "screen". Example: the notification is persistent, so it will be always showing on the notification drawer. If I'm on another app and I click the button on my notification, I want to open only the alert, but now it's opening the alert AND the screen with the layout for my activity.

Is there a way to show only the alert, without showing the activity? Or do I have to use another method to do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The suggestion from codeMagic is a good one. Simply create a layout for your notification activity which makes it look like an `AlertDialog` but give it the `Theme.Dialog` attribute. This makes it look like a 'dialog' popup but with the full functionality of an `Activity`. That means you won't need an `AlertDialog` at all and the `Activity` won't blank out the background so it will leave whatever other app partially visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no absolute need for an alert dialog, you can make the alert its own activity and just not use the alert builder. Put buttons and textviews or whatever you need as you would. Then in the manifest use

`<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">`

**[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)** is more about themes. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, feel free to add if I forgot something. I thought I had my code here at home where I did that but I was mistaken

Comment: @vdlow you're welcome. Let me know if you need something different or if it works for what you need you can accept so others with the same problem can find it easier

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much, the final result was better than I expected. I didn't know about themes & styles, I'll try to learn more about it. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Most stuff on Android is easy once you learn what its capable of. That's the tricky part is learning everything that you can do with it :)